# Team Foundation Online: Source Control - Making Specified Changeset Active

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2015

1. The issue that I am experiencing is that when I want to have specified Changeset active, file structure doesn't match with that Changeset. Example: In Changeset 146 I had some files. I want to go back on Changeset 142. That Changeset didn't have those files at the time. In solution I will still have files from Changeset 146. In pending changes I don't see those files. It's like that Source control doesn't recognize them.
   I don't know which Changeset is currently active one.
2. What will happen if I make changes on that version and do commit? Will I override all changes that was done after Changeset 142?

Comment: I suggest you be more specific, step by step, about what you did. Maybe try to reproduce it with some files you don't care about, just so you can tell us what you really did. Because what you're saying doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFVC as with other server based source systems users a linear model. Each changeset is a new unique watermark on top of the last one. So 146 is on top of 145. There is no easy to check in on top of another changeset.

When you rollback you are effectively checking in the previous changesets files as a new changeset. So if you roll back 143 there is no modification, beyond the files associated with that checkin. So if 145 changes other files then they will remain untouched.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in case you want to go back to an older version (just when you want to try out something) the easiest way is: Go to a "new folder" and checkout the desired Changeset? I think that is something we can live with.

Comment: Checkin in on top of another changeset would over complicate the process I think. So it seems logical to me, that every change also causes a new changeset (event when the change reverts something from a previous version).

Comment: I am still not sure what this all has to do, that a system could possibly detect, that you want to go back to an older version and ask you if you want to remove or keep files from a newer revision.

Comment: Yes, you can create an additional workspace and use "get specific" to retrieve your code at any state that you want.